# Passing/binding inputfield UIInput.value inside ui:repeat to bean method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I've comments that are displayed from an `<ui:repeat>` tag. An user can reply to to all comments with input fields that are displayed individually for each comment. However I can't manage to pass the value of the comment to the bean that deals with it. I thought about passing the UIInput value as described in the first answer [by balusC here][1]. The problem is that the content is empty because the action button is bound to every UIInput ( I believe so). I should sort of have a personal bound between each button and my UIInput. I think the code is gonna be more self-explanatory hopefully. :

```
<ui:repeat var="post" value="#{watchThread.listeFirstPosts}">                               
    <h:outputText value="#{post.user.username}"/>

    <div class="postContent">
        <h:outputText value="#{watchThread.sanitize(post.content)}" />
    </div>
    <div class="replyAction">
    <h:form>
        <div class="inputAreaPostFast">
            <p:inputTextarea id="reply2" value="#{watchThread.replyContent}" binding="#{inputReply}"/>
            <div class="replyBtn">

---------- Here the third param is the issue --------------
                <p:commandButton action="#{watchThread.sendReply(userNav.user, post, inputReply.value)}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Edit: This is the code that worked for me. (I think) I had a form that had no business of being in my ui:repeat tag. Also to bind the input see the answer/comment of balusC below. However I had to let the form tags inside and not outside as suggested.

```
        <ui:repeat var="post" value="#{watchThread.listeFirstPosts}">
            <div class="replyBlock">                        
                <h:panelGroup id="username" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <div class="profileimgForum">                   
                    <h:graphicImage styleClass="profilepicForum" value="/images/#{post.user.profilePic}" rendered="#{!empty post.user.profilePic}"></h:graphicImage> 
                    <h:graphicImage styleClass="profilepicForum" library="images" name="profilepic1.jpg" rendered="#{empty post.user.profilePic}"></h:graphicImage>     
                </div>
                <span class="posterTitle">
                <h:outputText value="#{post.user.username}"></h:outputText> </span>
                <h:outputText value="  #{watchThread.formatTimeReply(post.datePost)}"/>

                </h:panelGroup>

                <div class="replyContent">
                    <h:outputText value="#{watchThread.sanitize(post.content)}" style="pointer:cursor;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="replyAction">
                     <p:inplace id="facet" effect="none">
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            #{strings.Reply}
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:form>
                            <div class="inputAreaPostFast">
                                <p:inputTextarea id="reply2" cols="70" rows="7" value="#{watchThread.replyContent}" binding="#{inputReply}" maxlength="500"/>
                                <div class="replyBtn">
                                    <p:commandButton update="growl" style=" margin-right: 2em;" value="#{strings.Reply}" action="#{watchThread.sendReply(userNav.user, post, inputReply)}"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </h:form>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:inplace>
                </div>
                <ui:repeat var="areply" value="#{post.posts}">
                    #{areply.content} ----
                </ui:repeat>

            </div>


            <!-- ####### Dialog username ######## -->
            <p:overlayPanel for="username" id="usernamePanel" dynamic="true" showCloseIcon="true" appendToBody="1" dismissable="false">
                 <div class="dlgTopBlock">
                         <div class="dlgPicBlock">    
                            <h:graphicImage styleClass="profilePicDialog" value="/images/#{post.user.profilePic}" rendered="#{!empty post.user.profilePic}"/> 
                            <h:graphicImage styleClass="profilePicDialog" library="images" name="profilepic1.jpg" rendered="#{empty post.user.profilePic}"/>    
                         </div>
                         <div class="dlgTopSubBlock"><div class="dlgTopTitle">
                             <h:graphicImage styleClass="flag" library="images/flags" 
                                            name="#{post.user.countryBean.iso2}.png" 
                                            rendered="#{! empty post.user.countryBean.iso2}"/>
                            <h:link value="#{post.user.username}" outcome="/user.xhtml">
                                <f:param name="username" value="#{post.user.username}"></f:param>
                            </h:link>

                            </div>
                            <div class="dlgRep">
                                <h:outputText value="#{post.user.reputation} #{strings.repPoints} "></h:outputText>
                            </div>
                         <div class="dlgTopStatus">
                            <h:outputText value="#{post.user.status}"/></div>

                        </div>                      
             </div>
             <div class="btnDlg">
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{userNav.isUserConnected  and userNav.username != post.user.username}">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{usernavmsg.SendPM}" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed" onclick="PF('sendMsgDlg').show();"></p:commandButton> 
                    <p:commandButton id="addFriend" value="#{friendBean.btnText}" action="#{friendBean.addFriend()}" update="growl addFriend" icon="#{friendBean.icon}"
                                rendered="#{friendBean.rendered}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
             </div>

             <p:dialog header="#{usernavmsg.SendingTo}: #{post.user.username}" 
                       dynamic="true" modal="false" widgetVar="sendMsgDlg" minHeight="40">
                <h:form>
                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{pMbean.title}" rows="1" cols="110" id="title" >
                        <f:passThroughAttribute name="placeholder" value="#{usernavmsg.Title}"/>
                    </p:inputTextarea><br/><br/>
                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{pMbean.message}" id="msg" rows="10" cols="110" autoResize="true">
                        <f:passThroughAttribute name="placeholder" value="#{usernavmsg.YourMsg}"/>
                    </p:inputTextarea><br/>

                    <p:commandButton style="float:right;"  value="#{usernavmsg.Send}" action="#{pMbean.send(post.user)}" 
                                    onclick="PF('sendMsgDlg').hide();" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed" update="growl"></p:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
        </p:overlayPanel> 

        <!-- ######### End of dialog user ######## -->
        </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this only works for the first entry from the ui:repeat. In the others the method is not even called.

Comment: Yes, I did and I changed the parameter of the method to UIInput. Then I get the value and it works for the first entry. But not the others. However I cleaned a lot of irrelevant code from my original post but since I moved the form tags outside the ui:repeat, some code might be relevant now. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Nope. However I have a dialog and an overlay pannel nested in the ui:repeat. I edited my post to include those. I did a mistake on the first try and put another <h:form> tag outside the <ui:repeat> (I had 3 inside prior) and now that I deleted all forms within inside the ui:repeat (as in my edit) I get an NPE on uiinput.getSubmittedValue().toString();

Comment: @BalusC It works thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I reposted the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only visible mistake is the below:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{watchThread.listeFirstPosts}" var="post" ...>
    <p:inputTextarea ... value="#{watchThread.replyContent}">
```

You're basically binding the value of the input field of **every** iteration to one and same backing bean property. So, every iteration round will override the value of the previous iteration round. This is not right. The value of the input field must be bound to the current iteration round. I.e. it should basically have been as below:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{watchThread.listeFirstPosts}" var="post" ...>
    <p:inputTextarea ... value="#{post.replyContent}">
```

But, in this construct you actually don't need it. Just get rid of the `value` attribute altogether and rely on `binding` as you initially wanted to use.

---

Then, there's another mistake as pointed out in the comments: nesting forms. This is illegal in HTML. Don't write JSF code in such way that it produces illegal HTML. There would be another potential cause in form of a bug in Mojarra which only exposes in case you're using `<f:ajax>` in a nested `<ui:repeat>`. The solution to that would be using a fullworthy `UIData` component, such as `<h:dataTable>` or one of PrimeFaces grids.

Comment: For info I've refactored the code 1 year after and hit a similar issue. I've asked a question on SO and it might be a dupe of this. However this answer makes little sens in the context of the new one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013673/debug-update-moderl-phase-setter-not-being-called